# Como seguir desplazandose en un formulario cuando llego al final o al inicio de una ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

tengo un widget padre donde llamo a un widget llamado ListaCodigosLink. Este widget almacena cartas que se encuentran en un container rojo, puedo desplazarme dentro de la ListView.builder, el problema es que cuando se llega al principio del Listview.builder no se puede seguir subiendo en el formulario y cuando se llega al final de listview.builder entonces no se puede continuar bajando en el formulario, si puedo desplazarme si toco fuera del container, pero quiero poder desplazarme cuando llego al final o inicio del listview.builder como puedo resolverlo?

este body del widget padre donde llamo al widget ListaCodigosLink:

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            codLinkInput(),
            buttonBuscaCliente(context),
            ayuda(context),
            ListaCodigosLink( 
              onItemTap: (codLink) {
                _codLinkController.text = codLink.toString();
                tipoConsulta = 0;
                execute();
              } 
            ),
    
    ReCaptchaWebView(
          width: 1,
          height: 1,
          webViewColor: null,
          onTokenReceived: _onTokenReceived,
          
    ),
    visible == true ? _formulario() : Column(),
  ],
),
```

),

este el widget ListaCodigosLink

```
class ListaCodigosLink extends StatefulWidget {
  ListaCodigosLink({Key? key, required this.onItemTap}) : super(key: key); 
  final Function(int) onItemTap;   
  @override
  State<ListaCodigosLink> createState() => _ListaCodigosLinkState();
}

class _ListaCodigosLinkState extends State<ListaCodigosLink> {

  final GlobalKey _listViewKey = GlobalKey();

  final codigoProvider = ProviderCodigo();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return identificadorUsuario == 0 ? Column() 
    : _listarCodigos();
  }
  Widget _listarCodigos() {
    String token = tokenLogin['token'].toString();
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: codigoProvider.obtenerCodigos(token, identificadorUsuario),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
        }
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
        {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: const 
            [
              Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator()
              )
            ],
          );
        }       
        final datosDecodificados = json.decode(snapshot.data);
        final codigosLink = CodigosLink.fromJsonList(datosDecodificados);
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
            child: Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 350),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: 4.0,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),  // Radio de los bordes
              ),
              height: 350,
              child: ListView.builder(
                key: _listViewKey,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: codigosLink.items.length,
                itemBuilder: ( BuildContext context, int index ) {
                  return _listaObjetos(codigosLink.items[index], context);
                },
              )
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añade al listview `physics = NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`

Comment: si hago eso ya no puedo desplazarme dentro del listview

Comment: Pues tendrás que usar slivers, no te queda de otra. https://medium.com/comunidad-flutter/slivers-desenmascarado-a44781aa7597